# Searching a particular number from an ascii file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have an ascii file which contains below and also it contains junk characters

```
15÷Ø04 DF0002 6.212.6.2-8041104878701200000000001048787012 F100000000CR
150530803676875161200000000001184000 140000 000000001064 2001320000000000000204920C0000000000000000000000000000F 0000000000000000
15¦004515300500000058000 24610438037004028685066100610470205000000010437840000000010437840ROSS STORES #1326 PFLUGERVILLE US 531078660TX A 9100E9999995 1 908041A
15_R01 000000 210 594326132632853 000000000000 0 01326006848 000000000
15G04 DF0002 3 10.3-8041 104878702100000000001048787021 F100000000CR
15¾0558803712442423600000000010484000 000000 000000010437 2001320000000000000984960C0000000000000000000000000000F 0000000000000000
15².004515300500000041000 24610438037004028581778100610470205000000015150840000000015150840ROSS STORES #746 AUSTIN US 531078703TX A 9120E9999995 1 908041A
15‘h01 000000 210 594325974664671 000000000000 0 007460077542 000000000
15…J04 DF0002 2 12.2-8041 104878702700000000001048787027 F100000000CR
47qŒ004610430000000 0006407190 407190SOUTHLGCY 407190 3200320000 ALL 0
47õ£00461043000000 407190 4071900000 ALL 0
47¶Ñ004610430000000 0006461043 461043SOUTHBAMS 461043 4004330000 ALL 0
47v+00461043000000 461043 4610430000 ALL 0
47]004610430000000 1000472573 483074VI 483074 3200320000 ALL 0
47s³00461043000000 483074 4610430000 ALL 0
47¶Ó004610430000000 1000473675 489359PR 489359 4610430000 ALL 0
47h004610430000000 9000299347 ACQ GU 436424 436424 3200320000 ALL 0
47S00461043000000 436424 4610430000 ALL 0
47æ/004610430000000 9000447390 489359 VCR VROL 489359 4004350000 ALL 0
47Ÿ¬00461043000000- *** END OF VSS-100-W REPORT *** 0
46u¨004610430000009000299347001201804112017127 V1100W 9000299347ACQ GU 436424 NB000000000000436424 Y3200320000Y9999840000000 0
46t004610430000009000299347001201804112017127 V1100W 9000299347ACQ GU 436424 NB000000000000436424 Y4610430000Y9999840000000 0
47ëR004610430000001REPORT ID: VSS-100-W VISANET SETTLEMENT SERVICE PAGE: 1 0
478|00461043000000 REPORTING FOR: 9000299347 ACQ GU 436424 INTERNATIONAL SETTLEMENT SERVICE REPORT DATE: 10FEB18 0
47Ir00461043000000 WEEKLY SETTLEMENT REPORTING HIERARCHY LIST LAST CHANGE: 07MAY17 0
478ý00461043000000 SETTLEMENT CURRENCY: USD 0
```

I want to search the records in the file that starts with 15. How can i do using awk or sed command? Can someone help me out

Comment: you want to return the whole line or everything until the first whitespace?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... 1) reduce the sample size, few lines to indicate the problem is enough... 2) add complete expected output for given sample 3) add what you've tried yourself to solve it

Answer (score 1):

### grep

```
grep '^15' file
```

### awk

```
awk '/^15/ { print $0 }' file
```

### sed

```
sed -n '/^15/p' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way so that i can remove those junk characters from the ascii file?

Comment: What's your definition of "junk characters"?

Comment: Suppose for 15÷Ø04 "÷Ø" is the junk character

Comment: Try `sed -n 's/^15[^ ]* //gp' file`